# How create an application using api rest and sqflite to the app offline and online with minimum code

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am quite new to flutter and dart. I am creating a flutter application. How create an application using api rest and sqflite to reu the app offline and online with minimum code. Is it possible? I couldn't find the right documents using these 2 in same time.

Comment: Flutter was designed to be maximum accomplishment using minimum code, you have to be brief about your problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question!

Here is what I recommend you go through:

1. Interacting with a rest API - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
2. Interacting with SQLite - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

And as much as I don't like recommending Medium due to paywalls:

https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-get-data-from-a-rest-api-and-save-locally-in-a-sqlite-database-9a9de5867939